# info light button in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

How can I change this code so I have an info button in the right corner of the navigation bar instead of a word?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [self setTitle:@"About"];
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"info", @"")
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                            target:self
                                                            action:@selector(addAction:)] autorelease];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has often been asked.

```
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonInformationIcon.jpg"]; 
        //create the button and assign the image
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //set the frame of the button to the size of the image
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(anyActionYouWant) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button]autorelease];
```

Here's one solution, among several.

Answer (score 0):

Or... you could select from the drop-down list when adding a button to the title bar, which kind of button you want. You'd need to select the type "Info Light".